# In Python, I want to add a number to each element in a list, but I get [[0,1],2] instead of [0,1,2]. How to fix this?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have

```
listB=[[0,1],[1,2]]

listall=[0,1,2,3]
```

For each element in `listB`, I want to extend it to a length-3 element by adding a number that is in `listall` but not in this element. My desired output is the following list:

```
listC=[[0,1,2],[0,1,3],[1,2,3]]
```

As a first step, I tried the following code:

```
import numpy as np

listB=[[0,1],[1,2]]
listall=range(4)
listC=[]
for b in listB:
    difb=set(listall)-set(b)
    for i in difb:
        listC.append([b,i])
print(listC)
```

However, the output I got is:

```
[[[0,1],2],[[0,1],3],[[1,2],0],[[1,2],3]]
```

This is far from what I wanted. As each element in this output list has a subarray nested in it, also the numbers in each element are not ordered.  I need to at least turn it to [[0,1,2],[0,1,3],[0,1,2],[1,2,3]] first (and then get rid of the duplicates). What's the fastest (most efficient) way to achieve it? Thanks!

Comment: why is there a `numpy` tag?

Comment: @mozway I thought the solution might need numpy:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unpack the items in `b` when creating the new list

```
listC.append([*b,i])
```

or if its easier to understand, add a new list with i to list `b`

```
listC.append(b + [i])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very helpful, and solved my problem. An additional question: how to make [*b,i] or [b+[i]] sorted? I tried to do listC.append(np.sort([*b,i])), but it returns [array([0,1,2]),...,array([1,2,3])].

Comment: use `sorted` instead of `np.sort`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep only unique lists (unique in the sense that the exact set of its elements are not found elsewhere in `listC`) in `listC`, then you might want to consider replacing

```
listC.append([b,i])
```

with

```
new = set([*b, i])
if new not in listC:
    listC.append(new)
```

Then the final output becomes:

```
>>> listC = [list(c) for c in listC]
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```